# place common variables and functions to use across controllers in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

What is the best/standard way to put common variables and functions in Zend framework 2 (with doctrine), to be used across all the modules, specifically their controllers.

I read somewhere that our controllers should extend another controller (like AppCommonController) which, in turn, extends AbstractActionController. The AppCommonController will then define the common variables and functions that we can access in any controller that extends it.

Is there a better/standard way to do this?

---Updated---

Say for e.g., I want to check the current mode of my site (test or live) in most of my controllers (across different modules), and accordingly want to do the necessary in the actions.

I write following in some controller:

```
    private $__currentMode = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        //following will be set to Live or Test depending on a session value
        $this->setCurrentMode('Live');
    }

    public function setCurrentMode($mode)
    {
        $this->__currentMode = $mode;
    }

    public function getCurrentMode()
    {
        return $this->__currentMode;
    }
```

I believe it is a bad idea to put above code in all the controllers where I need to check the current mode.

So I want to put it (both the currentMode property and getter/setter functions) at some place from where I can access them in all the controllers wherever needed.

Comment: your question is a fair one, but your example is not good. To answer the question, consider using a trait. However, please don't ever use the example you have given, your code should not be aware of the environment it runs in. In particular code should not change behaviour for a test environment.

Comment: actually my application is something like a payment gateway back-end, with test mode where the payments made by customers go to payment_test table, and live mode where they go to payment_live table.. just that...so my code is actually mode dependent

Comment: Ah, @Prashant, that makes sense. The controller plugin suggestion below is also a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is what controller plugins are there for

First create a controller plugin...

```
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class MyModeHelper extends AbstractPlugin
{
    protected $mode;

    public function __construct($mode)
    { 
        $this->mode = $mode;
    }

    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->mode;
    }
}
```

Then tell the controller manager about it in Module.php using the `getControllerPluginConfig()` method

```
// in Application/Module.php
public function getControllerPluginConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'myModeHelper' => function($sm) {
                // get mode from environment
                $mode = 'live';
                return new Controller\Plugin\MyModeHelper($mode);
            }
         )
      ); //fixed syntax error
    }
}
```

Plugin should now be available any time you call it in a controller

```
// in your controllers
public function indexAction()
{
    if ($this->myModeHelper()->getMode() == 'live') {
        // do live stuff
    } else {
        // do test stuff
    }
    return new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: thanks! I wasn't aware about Controller Plugin, your solution helped.

Answer (score 1):

Well, heavily depends on the functions.

First of: variables would probably best placed inside configuration. From there on they are accessible anywhere a `ServiceLocator` is present.

As far as functions are concerned, it heavily depends on what the functions do. Are they some sort of ControllerLogic? Then your approach `Mymodule\Stdlib\Controller\Mycontroller` might be a good idea.

Looking at the current "Community-Standards" having general-purpose-code under the `Stdlib`-Namespace is commonly accepted.

Outside of the above i don't know what to tell you, as your question is pretty vague.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manuel. I have updated my question to include the example for what I seek. What do you suggest now?